# How to debug the JavaScript error "Uncaught TypeError: X is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, javascript-objects

I am making an eCard that has square confetti falling from the top of the canvas to the bottom and then resetting.

I got it to work with 1 confetti object, but I thought it would be nice to create an array of confetti objects so with 1 variable change(NUM_CONFETTI) I can change the amount of confetti without errors,

The error I am getting reads:

> TestPC.js:265 Uncaught TypeError: Confetti is not a constructor
>       at TestPC.js:265

The relevant lines of code are:

```
var NUM_CONFETTI = 10;
var Confetti = new Array();

//create confetti object array
for (i = 0; i < NUM_CONFETTI; i++) {
    Confetti[i] = new Confetti(20,20,20,20,"red","blue",0,50);
}
```

I realize that at the moment all the objects will have the same exact values I have a RandomNumberGetter() function to fix that after the error is cleared.  Full code is posted below if you wish to run it:

```
//james gossling multimedia for web design spring 2018
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var RandomGetter = function(min, max) {
    //set mins and maxes for ball speed to change angle slightly after ball reset
    min = min;
    max = max;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};  
//game classes go here
var Background = function(context,color) {
    this.context = context;
    this.color = color;
};
Background.prototype = {

    DrawBackground: function() {
    //for testing
    //console.log('here')
    context.strokeStyle = this.color;
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.stroke(); // invoke stroke
    context.fill(); // invoke fill
    context.closePath();
},


};

Confetti = function(x, y, width, height, stroke, fill, translateFactor, fallSpeed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.stroke = stroke;
    this.fill = fill;
    this.translateFactor = translateFactor;
    this.fallSpeed = fallSpeed;
};
Confetti.prototype = {
    Draw: function(x, y, width, height, stroke, fill, translateFactor) {
        context.strokeStyle = stroke;
        context.fillStyle = fill;
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(x, y, width, height);
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
    },
    GetX: function() {
        return this.x;
    },
    GetY: function() {
        return this.y;
    },
    GetWidth: function() {
        return this.width;
    },
    GetHeight: function() {
        return this.height;
    },
    GetStroke: function() {
        return this.stroke;
    },
    GetFill: function() {
        return this.fill;
    },
    GetTranslateFactor: function() {
        return this.translateFactor;
    },
    GetFallSpeed: function() {
        return this.fallSpeed;
    },

    Update: function(modifier) {
        this.y = this.y + (this.fallSpeed * modifier);
        if (this.y > canvas.height) {this.y = 0;}
    },

};

var DrawConfetti = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_CONFETTI; i++) {
        Confetti[i].Draw(Confetti[i].GetX(),Confetti[i].GetY(),Confetti[i].GetWidth(),Confetti[i].GetHeight(),Confetti[i].GetStroke(),Confetti[i].GetFill(),Confetti[i].GetTranslateFactor());
    }
}

var UpdateConfetti = function(modifier) {
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_CONFETTI; i++) {
        Confetti[i].Update(modifier);
    }
};

Firework = function() {

};
Firework.prototype = {



};

UncleSam = function() {

};
UncleSam.prototype = {



};

Text = function(context,title,x,y,color) {
    this.context = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.lineWidth = 2;
    this.lineHeight =(this.context.measureText('W').width) + Math.pow((this.context.measureText('W').width),2);
    this.font = '70pt Times New Roman';
    //GET METRICS
    this.metrics = this.context.measureText(this.title);
    this.width = this.metrics.width;
    this.maxWidth = canvas.width;
    this.GradChangeSpeed = 1;
    this.GradChangeOffset = 0;
    this.debugCounter = 0;
};
Text.prototype = {

    SetAttributes: function() {
        context.font
        context.textAlign = 'center'
        context.font = this.font;
        context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
        context.lineHeight = this.GetHeight;
        context.fillStyle = TextGradient;
        context.strokeStyle = this.color;
        //shadow attributes
        context.shadowColor = undefined;
        context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
        context.shadowBlur = 0;
    },
    //GETTTERS SETTERS///////////////////
    GetTextX: function() {
        return this.x;
    },
    GetTextY: function() {
        return this.y;
    },
    GetTextLineHeight: function() {
        return this.lineHeight;
    },
    GetTextWidth: function() {
        return this.width;
    },
    //GETTERS SETTERS////////////
    SetColorGradient: function() {
        TextGradient.addColorStop(0,"red");
        TextGradient.addColorStop(this.GradChangeOffset,"white");
        TextGradient.addColorStop(.7,"blue");
    },
    Update: function(modifier) {
        this.GradChangeOffset = this.GradChangeOffset + (this.GradChangeSpeed * modifier);
        context.strokeText(this.GradChangeOffset.toFixed(2),canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
        if (this.GradChangeOffset > 1) {this.GradChangeOffset = .1;}
    },

    DrawText: function() {
        this.WrapText(this.context, this.title, this.x, this.y, this.maxWidth, this.lineHeight);
    },

    WrapText: function(context, title, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {

        var words = title.split(' ');
        var line = '';

        for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
            var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
            var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
            var testWidth = metrics.width;

            if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
                context.fillText(line, x, y);
                context.strokeText(line, x, y);
                line = words[n] + ' ';
                y += lineHeight;
            }
            else {
                line = testLine;
            }
        }

        context.fillText(line, x, y);
        context.strokeText(line, x, y);
    },

};

//other functions
var ClearScreen = function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};

var DrawObjects = function() {
    ClearScreen();
    Background1.DrawBackground();
    Text1.SetAttributes();
    Text1.SetColorGradient();
    Text1.DrawText();
    //Confetti1.Draw(Confetti1.GetX(),Confetti1.GetY(),Confetti1.GetWidth(),Confetti1.GetHeight(),Confetti1.GetStroke(),Confetti1.GetFill(),Confetti1.GetTranslateFactor(),Confetti1.GetFallSpeed());
    DrawConfetti();
};

var UpdateObjects = function(modifier) {
    Text1.Update(modifier);
    UpdateConfetti(modifier);
};


var Reset = function() {

};
//MAIN GAME LOOP FXN///////////////////
// The main game loop
var main = function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;
    var frameRateAdjust = delta/1000;

    DrawObjects(frameRateAdjust);

    UpdateObjects(frameRateAdjust);

    then = now;

    //possibly do RESET

    // Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

//START ECARD
//create variables
var then = Date.now();
var NUM_CONFETTI = 10;
var Confetti = [NUM_CONFETTI];

//create objects
Background1 = new Background(context,'black');
var Text1 = new Text(context,'Happy 4th of July!',canvas.width/2,canvas.height/10,'red');
var TextGradient = context.createLinearGradient(Text1.GetTextX(),Text1.GetTextY(),Text1.GetTextX()+Text1.GetTextWidth(),Text1.GetTextY()+Text1.GetTextLineHeight()/2)

//create confetti object array
for (i = 0; i < NUM_CONFETTI; i++) {
    //Confetti[i] = new Confetti(RandomGetter(0,canvas.width),-10,RandomGetter(5,30),RandomGetter(5,30),"red","blue",RandomGetter(0,1),RandomGetter(30,50));
Confetti[i] = new Confetti(20,20,20,20,"red","blue",0,50);
}

//start eCard animations
Reset();
main();
```

Comment: You overwrite your "Confetti" function from line 33 with your "Confetti" array on line 255.

Comment: Your subject line is misleading.   Creating an array is easy and you appear to know perfectly well how to do that, but first you have to fix that `Confetti is not a constructor` error.

Comment: duly noted, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like the problem is that you have a constructor named Confetti  and also an array named Confetti.   try  replacing:

```
var Confetti = new Array();
```

with

```
var confettiArr = [];
```

then do:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_CONFETTI; i++) {
    confettiArr.push(new Confetti(20,20,20,20,"red","blue",0,50));
}
```

Comment: it would be more conventional to use an all lower case (or camel case) name for the array, reserving names that start with an upper case letter for the classes themselves.

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for catching that. I updated the answer.